# Invalid factor level error when pushing values into data frame

Tags: r

I have the following code that is aimed at going to a website, fetching some data and putting it in a data.frame

```
create_links <- function(keyword, distance) {

 data.frame <- data.frame(character(), character())
 postcode <- c(3511, 4000, 5000)

 var_website1 <- "http://www.marktplaats.nl/z.html?query="
 var_website2 <- "&postcode="
 var_website3 <- "&distance="

 for (i in 1:length(postcode)) {

    website <- paste0(var_website1, keyword, var_website2, postcode[i], var_website3, distance)

    html <- read_html(website)
    number <- html_nodes(html, "h1 span")

    number <- as.character(number)
    website <- as.character(website)
    data.frame <- rbind(data.frame, number, website)
 }
data.frame
}
```

When Im calling the formula:
     library(rvest)
     create_links("bureaustoel", 10000)

All seems to work but I only have a small hassle with putting the values in the data.frame. I get the following error:

```
1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = "<span>20.474 resultaten voor 'bureaustoel'</span>") :
invalid factor level, NA generated
2: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = "http://www.marktplaats.nl/z.html?query=bureaustoel&postcode=4000&distance=10000") :
invalid factor level, NA generated
3: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = "<span>20.474 resultaten voor 'bureaustoel'</span>") :
invalid factor level, NA generated
```

I dont get why I get the errors though (cause Im converting the values into characters before pushing it into the data.frame?

Any thoughts?

Comment: add `stringsAsFactors=F` to your data.frame() declaration.. it's not the values your are adding, it's with the way the data.frame is created (both columns are factors).  I would also recommend using a different naming convention for your data.frames in the future to avoid using base R keywords (use `df` or something like that).

Comment: @devmacrile thanks for your help. If I ad it to my data.frame (data.frame <- data.frame(character(), character(), stringsAsFactors=F)
) I still get the same error... Other suggestions?

Comment: Hmm, yeah it seems like `rbind()` still wants to make those columns factors.  You could assign the row by index which should work, i.e. `df[i, ] <- c(number, website)`.  You shouldn't necessarily have to pre-allocate the data frame to do this, but it's best practice to do so, so I would define your data frame after your define `postcode` as something like: `df <- data.frame(rep("", length(postcode)), rep("", length(postcode)), stringsAsFactors = F)`.